# How to send object with buffer from addon to node threadsafe?

Tags: c++, node.js, node-addon-api, n-api

I am trying to send an object from addon to node but get:
`no matching function for call to ‘Napi::Object::New(Napi::Env&, Napi::Object&)’`.

How can I achieve that.

Any help will be appreciated.
Below is the code in question.

`std::shared_ptr<ThreadSafeCallback> callback = NULL;` // declared globally

```
callback = std::make_shared<ThreadSafeCallback> (info[0].As<Function>());    
std::thread([callback]
{
    try
    {
          callback->call([result, data](Napi::Env env, std::vector<napi_value>& args){
          const unsigned char* t = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>( "123" );
          Object obj = Object::New(env);
          obj.Set("name", "world");
          obj.Set("frame", (char *)t);
            args = { env.Undefined(), Napi::Object::New(env, obj) }; // faile here
            // would like to have {"name": test, frame: buf}
          });
    }
}).detach();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just changed Napi::Object::New to Napi::Object::Value. Its in the docs, but somehow i missed it.